# Replace image in an <img> with CSS

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to create an hover state on a logo following [this article from CSS-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/replace-the-image-in-an-img-with-css/), but I'm unable to make it work.

I'm using a WordPress theme where I can only edit the CSS (and JS but I don't know anything about that).

**CSS-Tricks code :**

HTML

```
<head>
  <title>Really Cool Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- .header would be across site on other pages with different children, so no background image adding -->
  <div class="header">
    <img class="banner" src="//notrealdomain1.com/banner.png">
  </div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
/* All in one selector */
.banner {
  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://notrealdomain2.com/newbanner.png) no-repeat;
  width: 180px; /* Width of new image */
  height: 236px; /* Height of new image */
  padding-left: 180px; /* Equal to width of new image */
}
```

[Website I'm working on](http://couill.art)

HTML

```
            <style>html{margin-top:0px!important;}#wpadminbar{top:auto!important;bottom:0;}}</style>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/favicon.png" sizes="32x32">   </head>
    <body class="home page-template-default page page-id-15 logged-in is-frontend dynamic-mode mejs-semplice-ui"bgcolor="transparent">
        <div id="content-holder" data-active-post="15">

                        <header class="nav_k3sck19qn semplice-navbar active-navbar non-sticky-nav  menu-type-text cover-transparent scroll-to-top" data-cover-transparent="enabled" data-bg-overlay-visibility="hidden"data-mobile-fallback="disabled">
                            <div class="container" data-nav="logo-left-menu-right">
                                <div class="navbar-inner menu-type-text" data-xl-width="12" data-navbar-type="container">
                                    <div class="logo navbar-left"><a href="http://couill.art" title="Couillard"><img src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/logo-Couillart-gif.png" alt="logo"></a></div>
                                    <nav class="standard navbar-right" data-font="font_dqju2lgtu"><ul class="menu"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="http://couill.art/about"><span>?</span></a></li>
</ul></nav>
                                    <div class="hamburger navbar-right semplice-menu"><a class="open-menu menu-icon"><span></span></a></div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </header>

                <div id="overlay-menu">
                    <div class="overlay-menu-inner" data-xl-width="12">
                        <nav class="overlay-nav" data-justify="center" data-align="align-middle" data-font="font_0kez4ul50">
                            <ul class="container"><li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="http://couill.art/about"><span>?</span></a></li>
</ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>


            <div id="content-15" class="content-container active-content  hide-on-init">
                <div class="sections">

                    <section id="section_2xzeiiwq2" class="content-block" data-column-mode-sm="single" data-column-mode-xs="single" data-layout="fluid" data-gutter="no" data-height="dynamic" >

                        <div class="container">
                        <div id="row_ogt8idpm2" class="row"><div id="column_k1k9lrm15" class="column" data-xl-width="12" >
                    <div class="content-wrapper">

                <div id="content_g6nt8g63h" class="column-content" data-module="portfoliogrid">

        <div id="masonry-content_g6nt8g63h" class="masonry">
            <div class="masonry-item-width"></div>
            <div id="project-17" class="masonry-item thumb masonry-content_g6nt8g63h-item below" data-xl-width="6" data-sm-width="6" data-xs-width="12"><a href="http://couill.art/project/danger-zone">
                <div class="thumb-inner">

            <div class="thumb-hover">
                <div class="thumb-hover-meta top-left hide-both fade">
                    <p>
                        <span class="title" data-font="regular">Danger Zone</span><br />
                        <span class="category" data-font="regular">Animation</span>
                    </p>            
                </div>
            </div>


                    <img src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Danger-Zone-0-00-39-00.jpg" width="1440" height="1080">
            </div></a><a class="regular" href="http://couill.art/project/danger-zone" title="Danger Zone"></a></div><div id="project-24" class="masonry-item thumb masonry-content_g6nt8g63h-item below" data-xl-width="6" data-sm-width="6" data-xs-width="12"><a href="http://couill.art/project/danger-ii">
                <div class="thumb-inner">

            <div class="thumb-hover">
                <div class="thumb-hover-meta top-left hide-both fade">
                    <p>
                        <span class="title" data-font="regular">Danger II</span><br />
                        <span class="category" data-font="regular">Animation</span>
                    </p>            
                </div>
            </div>


                    <img src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Danger-Zone-0-00-37-04.jpg" width="1440" height="1080">
            </div></a><a class="regular" href="http://couill.art/project/danger-ii" title="Danger II"></a></div>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            (function ($) {
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    // delete old css if there
                    $("#content_g6nt8g63h-style").remove();
                    // add css to head
                    $("head").append('<style id="content_g6nt8g63h-style" type="text/css">#masonry-content_g6nt8g63h{ margin: auto -0px !important; } .masonry-content_g6nt8g63h-item { margin: 0px; padding-left: 0px; padding-right: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; }#content-holder .thumb .thumb-inner .thumb-hover {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);}#content-holder .thumb .thumb-hover-meta { padding: 2.22rem; }#content-holder .thumb .thumb-hover-meta .title { color: #ffffff; font-size: 1.33rem; text-transform: none; }#content-holder .thumb .thumb-hover-meta .category { color: #999999; font-size: 1rem; text-transform: none; }#content-holder #project-17 .thumb-inner .thumb-hover {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);background-image: url(http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/danger-zone-titre-bis.png);background-size: cover;background-position: 50% 50%;}#content-holder #project-17 .thumb-hover-meta { padding: 2.22rem; }#content-holder #project-17 .thumb-hover-meta .title { color: #ffffff; font-size: 1.33rem; text-transform: none; }#content-holder #project-17 .thumb-hover-meta .category { color: #999999; font-size: 1rem; text-transform: none; }#content-holder #project-24 .thumb-inner .thumb-hover {background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);background-image: url(http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/Carlton-Dance-squelette.gif);background-size: cover;background-position: 50% 50%;}#content-holder #project-24 .thumb-hover-meta { padding: 2.22rem; }#content-holder #project-24 .thumb-hover-meta .title { color: #ffffff; font-size: 1.33rem; text-transform: none; }#content-holder #project-24 .thumb-hover-meta .category { color: #999999; font-size: 1rem; text-transform: none; }#content-holder #content_g6nt8g63h .thumb .post-title { padding-top: 1rem; } #content_g6nt8g63h .thumb .post-title, #content_g6nt8g63h .thumb .post-title a { color: #000000; font-size: 16px; text-transform: none; } #content_g6nt8g63h .thumb .post-title span, #content_g6nt8g63h .thumb .post-title a span { color: #999999; font-size: 14px; text-transform: none; padding-top: 0.4444444444444444rem; }</style>');
                    // define container
                    var $container = $("#masonry-content_g6nt8g63h");
                    // make jquery object out of items
                    var $items = $(".masonry-content_g6nt8g63h-item");

                    // fire masmonry
                    $container.masonry({
                        itemSelector: ".masonry-content_g6nt8g63h-item",
                        columnWidth: ".masonry-item-width",
                        transitionDuration: 0,
                        isResizable: true,
                        percentPosition: true,
                    });

                    // show images
                    showImages($container, $items);

                    // load images and reveal if loaded
                    function showImages($container, $items) {
                        // get masonry
                        var msnry = $container.data("masonry");
                        // get item selector
                        var itemSelector = msnry.options.itemSelector;
                        // append items to masonry container
                        //$container.append($items);
                        $items.imagesLoaded().progress(function(imgLoad, image) {
                            // get item
                            var $item = $(image.img).parents(itemSelector);
                            // fade in item
                            // layout
                            msnry.layout();
                            // fade in item
                            $item.css("opacity", 1);
                        });
                    }
                });
            })(jQuery);
        </script>

                </div>

                    </div>
                </div></div>
                        </div>
                    </section>              

                    <section id="section_866a48a67" class="content-block footercustom" data-column-mode-sm="single" data-column-mode-xs="single" data-valign="top" data-justify="center" data-layout="grid" data-gutter="yes" data-height="dynamic" >

                        <div class="container">
                        <div id="row_93abd0448" class="row"><div id="column_6a2300a14" class="column" data-xl-width="12" >
                    <div class="content-wrapper">

                <div id="content_42677fa93" class="column-content" data-module="code">

                <div class="is-content ce-code">
                    <h6>2018 &copy; Couillard<h6>
                </div>

                </div>

                    </div>
                </div></div>
                        </div>
                    </section>              

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="pswp" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="pswp__bg"></div>
    <div class="pswp__scroll-wrap">
        <div class="pswp__container">
            <div class="pswp__item"></div>
            <div class="pswp__item"></div>
            <div class="pswp__item"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="pswp__ui pswp__ui--hidden">
            <div class="pswp__top-bar">
                <div class="pswp__counter"></div>
                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--close" title="Close (Esc)"></button>
                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--share" title="Share"></button>
                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--fs" title="Toggle fullscreen"></button>
                <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--zoom" title="Zoom in/out"></button>
                <div class="pswp__preloader">
                    <div class="pswp__preloader__icn">
                      <div class="pswp__preloader__cut">
                        <div class="pswp__preloader__donut"></div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="pswp__share-modal pswp__share-modal--hidden pswp__single-tap">
                <div class="pswp__share-tooltip"></div> 
            </div>
            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--left" title="Previous (arrow left)">
            </button>
            <button class="pswp__button pswp__button--arrow--right" title="Next (arrow right)">
            </button>
            <div class="pswp__caption">
                <div class="pswp__caption__center"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  <div class="back-to-top">
        <a class="semplice-event" data-event-type="helper" data-event="scrollToTop"><svg version="1.1" id="Ebene_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
     width="53px" height="20px" viewBox="0 0 53 20" enable-background="new 0 0 53 20" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Ebene_3">
</g>
<g>
    <polygon points="43.886,16.221 42.697,17.687 26.5,4.731 10.303,17.688 9.114,16.221 26.5,2.312   "/>
</g>
</svg>
</a>
    </div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
/* <![CDATA[ */
var semplice = {"default_api_url":"http:\/\/couill.art\/wp-json","semplice_api_url":"http:\/\/couill.art\/wp-json\/semplice\/v1\/frontend","template_dir":"http:\/\/couill.art\/wp-content\/themes\/semplice4","category_base":"\/category\/","tag_base":"\/tag\/","nonce":"c683bb18db","frontend_mode":"dynamic","static_transitions":"disabled","site_name":"Couillard","base_url":"http:\/\/couill.art","frontpage_id":"15","blog_home":"http:\/\/couill.art","blog_navbar":"","sr_status":"enabled","blog_sr_status":"enabled","is_preview":"","password_form":"\r\n\t\t<div class=\"post-password-form\">\r\n\t\t\t<div class=\"inner\">\r\n\t\t\t\t<form action=\"http:\/\/couill.art\/wp-login.php?action=postpass\" method=\"post\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"password-lock\"><svg xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2000\/svg\" width=\"35\" height=\"52\" viewBox=\"0 0 35 52\">\r\n  <path id=\"Form_1\" data-name=\"Form 1\" d=\"M31.3,25.028H27.056a0.755,0.755,0,0,1-.752-0.757V14.654a8.8,8.8,0,1,0-17.608,0v9.616a0.755,0.755,0,0,1-.752.757H3.7a0.755,0.755,0,0,1-.752-0.757V14.654a14.556,14.556,0,1,1,29.111,0v9.616A0.755,0.755,0,0,1,31.3,25.028Zm-3.495-1.514h2.743V14.654a13.051,13.051,0,1,0-26.1,0v8.859H7.192V14.654a10.309,10.309,0,1,1,20.617,0v8.859Zm4.43,28.475H2.761A2.77,2.77,0,0,1,0,49.213V25.28a1.763,1.763,0,0,1,1.755-1.766H33.242A1.763,1.763,0,0,1,35,25.28V49.213A2.77,2.77,0,0,1,32.239,51.988ZM1.758,25.028a0.252,0.252,0,0,0-.251.252V49.213a1.259,1.259,0,0,0,1.254,1.262H32.239a1.259,1.259,0,0,0,1.254-1.262V25.28a0.252,0.252,0,0,0-.251-0.252H1.758ZM20.849,43h-6.7a0.75,0.75,0,0,1-.61-0.314,0.763,0.763,0,0,1-.1-0.682l1.471-4.44a4.1,4.1,0,1,1,5.184,0L21.563,42a0.763,0.763,0,0,1-.1.682A0.75,0.75,0,0,1,20.849,43ZM15.2,41.487H19.8l-1.319-3.979a0.76,0.76,0,0,1,.33-0.891,2.6,2.6,0,1,0-2.633,0,0.76,0.76,0,0,1,.33.891Z\"\/>\r\n<\/svg>\r\n<\/div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<p>This content is protected. <br \/><span>To view, please enter the password.<\/span><\/p>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"input-fields\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<input name=\"post_password\" class=\"post-password-input\" type=\"password\" size=\"20\" maxlength=\"20\" placeholder=\"Enter password\" \/><a class=\"post-password-submit semplice-event\" data-event-type=\"helper\" data-event=\"postPassword\" data-id=\"15\">Submit<\/a>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t\t\t<\/form>\r\n\t\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t","gallery":{"prev":"<svg version=\"1.1\" id=\"Ebene_1\" xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2000\/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/1999\/xlink\" x=\"0px\" y=\"0px\"\n\twidth=\"18px\" height=\"40px\"  viewBox=\"0 0 18 40\" enable-background=\"new 0 0 18 40\" xml:space=\"preserve\">\n<g id=\"Ebene_2\">\n\t<g>\n\t\t<polygon points=\"16.3,40 0.3,20 16.3,0 17.7,1 2.5,20 17.7,39 \t\t\"\/>\n\t<\/g>\n<\/g>\n<\/svg>\n","next":"<svg version=\"1.1\" id=\"Ebene_1\" xmlns=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/2000\/svg\" xmlns:xlink=\"http:\/\/www.w3.org\/1999\/xlink\" x=\"0px\" y=\"0px\"\n\twidth=\"18px\" height=\"40px\" viewBox=\"0 0 18 40\" enable-background=\"new 0 0 18 40\" xml:space=\"preserve\">\n<g id=\"Ebene_2\">\n\t<g>\n\t\t<polygon points=\"0.3,39 15.5,20 0.3,1 1.7,0 17.7,20 1.7,40 \t\t\"\/>\n\t<\/g>\n<\/g>\n<\/svg>\n"},"menus":{"nav_k3sck19qn":{"html":"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<header class=\"nav_k3sck19qn semplice-navbar active-navbar non-sticky-nav  menu-type-text cover-transparent scroll-to-top\" data-cover-transparent=\"enabled\" data-bg-overlay-visibility=\"hidden\"data-mobile-fallback=\"disabled\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"container\" data-nav=\"logo-left-menu-right\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"navbar-inner menu-type-text\" data-xl-width=\"12\" data-navbar-type=\"container\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"logo navbar-left\"><a href=\"http:\/\/couill.art\" title=\"Couillard\"><img src=\"http:\/\/couill.art\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/05\/logo-Couillart-gif.png\" alt=\"logo\"><\/a><\/div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<nav class=\"standard navbar-right\" data-font=\"font_dqju2lgtu\"><ul class=\"menu\"><li id=\"menu-item-28\" class=\"menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28\"><a href=\"http:\/\/couill.art\/about\"><span>?<\/span><\/a><\/li>\n<\/ul><\/nav>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"hamburger navbar-right semplice-menu\"><a class=\"open-menu menu-icon\"><span><\/span><\/a><\/div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/header>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div id=\"overlay-menu\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"overlay-menu-inner\" data-xl-width=\"12\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<nav class=\"overlay-nav\" data-justify=\"center\" data-align=\"align-middle\" data-font=\"font_0kez4ul50\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<ul class=\"container\"><li class=\"menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28\"><a href=\"http:\/\/couill.art\/about\"><span>?<\/span><\/a><\/li>\n<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/nav>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t","css":".nav_k3sck19qn { background-color: transparent;; }.nav_k3sck19qn { height: 6.666666666666667rem; }.is-frontend #content-holder .sections { margin-top: 6.666666666666667rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn { padding-top: 3.3333333333333335rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn { padding-bottom: 3.3333333333333335rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .logo img, .nav_k3sck19qn .logo svg { width: 2.7777777777777777rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .logo { align-items: center; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger { align-items: center; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { background-color: #2592ff; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { width: 1.6666666666666667rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li a span { font-size: 1.6666666666666667rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li a span { color: #2592ff; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li a { padding-left: 0rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li a { padding-right: 0rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li a span { text-transform: none; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li a span { letter-spacing: 0rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li a:hover span, .navbar-inner nav ul li.current-menu-item a span, .navbar-inner nav ul li.current_page_item a span { color: #000000; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li.current-menu-item a span { color: #000000; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li.current_page_item a span { color: #000000; }.single-project .navbar-inner nav ul li.portfolio-grid a span { color: #000000; }#overlay-menu { background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1); }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav { text-align: center; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li a { padding-top: 0rem; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li a { padding-bottom: 0rem; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li a span { text-transform: none; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li a span { border-bottom-color: #eaeaea; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li a:hover span { color: #000000; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li.current-menu-item a span { color: #000000; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li.current_page_item a span { color: #000000; }.single-project #overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li.portfolio-grid a span { color: #000000; }#overlay-menu nav ul li a:hover span { border-bottom-color: #000000; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li.current-menu-item a span { border-bottom-color: #000000; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li.current_page_item a span { border-bottom-color: #000000; }.single-project #overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li.portfolio-grid a span { border-bottom-color: #000000; }@media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1169.9px) { .nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }}@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.9px) { .nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }}@media screen and (min-width: 544px) and (max-width: 767.9px) { .nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }}@media screen and (max-width: 543.9px) { .nav_k3sck19qn .logo img, .nav_k3sck19qn .logo svg { width: 1.6666666666666667rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }}","mobile_css":{"lg":".nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }","md":".nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }","sm":".nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }","xs":".nav_k3sck19qn .logo img, .nav_k3sck19qn .logo svg { width: 1.6666666666666667rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }"}},"default":"nav_k3sck19qn","system_default":{"html":"\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<header class=\"nav_k3sck19qn semplice-navbar active-navbar non-sticky-nav  menu-type-text cover-transparent scroll-to-top\" data-cover-transparent=\"enabled\" data-bg-overlay-visibility=\"hidden\"data-mobile-fallback=\"disabled\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"container\" data-nav=\"logo-left-menu-right\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"navbar-inner menu-type-text\" data-xl-width=\"12\" data-navbar-type=\"container\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"logo navbar-left\"><a href=\"http:\/\/couill.art\" title=\"Couillard\"><img src=\"http:\/\/couill.art\/wp-content\/uploads\/2018\/05\/logo-Couillart-gif.png\" alt=\"logo\"><\/a><\/div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<nav class=\"standard navbar-right\" data-font=\"font_dqju2lgtu\"><ul class=\"menu\"><li class=\"menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28\"><a href=\"http:\/\/couill.art\/about\"><span>?<\/span><\/a><\/li>\n<\/ul><\/nav>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"hamburger navbar-right semplice-menu\"><a class=\"open-menu menu-icon\"><span><\/span><\/a><\/div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/header>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t<div id=\"overlay-menu\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<div class=\"overlay-menu-inner\" data-xl-width=\"12\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<nav class=\"overlay-nav\" data-justify=\"center\" data-align=\"align-middle\" data-font=\"font_0kez4ul50\">\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t<ul class=\"container\"><li class=\"menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28\"><a href=\"http:\/\/couill.art\/about\"><span>?<\/span><\/a><\/li>\n<\/ul>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t\t<\/nav>\r\n\t\t\t\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t\t\t<\/div>\r\n\t\t\t\r\n\t\t\t\t\t","css":".nav_k3sck19qn { background-color: transparent;; }.nav_k3sck19qn { height: 6.666666666666667rem; }.is-frontend #content-holder .sections { margin-top: 6.666666666666667rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn { padding-top: 3.3333333333333335rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn { padding-bottom: 3.3333333333333335rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .logo img, .nav_k3sck19qn .logo svg { width: 2.7777777777777777rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .logo { align-items: center; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger { align-items: center; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { background-color: #2592ff; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { width: 1.6666666666666667rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li a span { font-size: 1.6666666666666667rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li a span { color: #2592ff; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li a { padding-left: 0rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li a { padding-right: 0rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li a span { text-transform: none; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li a span { letter-spacing: 0rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li a:hover span, .navbar-inner nav ul li.current-menu-item a span, .navbar-inner nav ul li.current_page_item a span { color: #000000; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li.current-menu-item a span { color: #000000; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner nav ul li.current_page_item a span { color: #000000; }.single-project .navbar-inner nav ul li.portfolio-grid a span { color: #000000; }#overlay-menu { background-color: rgba(245, 245, 245, 1); }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav { text-align: center; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li a { padding-top: 0rem; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li a { padding-bottom: 0rem; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li a span { text-transform: none; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li a span { border-bottom-color: #eaeaea; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li a:hover span { color: #000000; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li.current-menu-item a span { color: #000000; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li.current_page_item a span { color: #000000; }.single-project #overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li.portfolio-grid a span { color: #000000; }#overlay-menu nav ul li a:hover span { border-bottom-color: #000000; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li.current-menu-item a span { border-bottom-color: #000000; }#overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li.current_page_item a span { border-bottom-color: #000000; }.single-project #overlay-menu .overlay-menu-inner nav ul li.portfolio-grid a span { border-bottom-color: #000000; }@media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1169.9px) { .nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }}@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.9px) { .nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }}@media screen and (min-width: 544px) and (max-width: 767.9px) { .nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }}@media screen and (max-width: 543.9px) { .nav_k3sck19qn .logo img, .nav_k3sck19qn .logo svg { width: 1.6666666666666667rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }}","mobile_css":{"lg":".nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }","md":".nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }","sm":".nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }","xs":".nav_k3sck19qn .logo img, .nav_k3sck19qn .logo svg { width: 1.6666666666666667rem; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon { height: 4px; }.nav_k3sck19qn .navbar-inner .hamburger a.menu-icon span { margin-top: 2px; }"}}},"post_ids":{"work":"15","danger-zone":"17","danger-ii":"24","about":"27","28":"28","footer-duplicate":"35","footer-blanc-duplicate":"41","about-2":"48"},"transition":{"in":{"effect":"fadeIn","position":"normal","visibility":"transition-hidden","ease":"Linear","duration":0.6,"easing":"Power3.easeIn"},"out":{"effect":"fadeOut","position":"normal","visibility":"transition-hidden","ease":"Linear","duration":0.6,"easing":"Power3.easeIn"},"status":"enabled","preset":"fade","scrollToTop":"enabled"},"sr_options":{"easing":"ease-out","duration":"600"}};
/* ]]> */
</script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://couill.art/wp-content/themes/semplice4/assets/js/frontend.min.js?ver=4.2.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://couill.art/wp-includes/js/wp-embed.min.js?ver=4.9.5'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

My extra CSS

```
.logo:hover img {
    display: block;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url(http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/logo-Couillart.gif) no-repeat;
    width: 50px; /* Width of new image */
    height: 50px; /* Height of new image */
    padding-left: 50px; /* Equal to width of new image */
}
```

I tried playing with the settings but I'm running out of ideas.

Comment: To start with, try changing `.logo:hover img` for `.header:hover img` in the css as I see no element in your html with `logo` class.

Comment: There's no `logo` class to target it's hover state.

Comment: @jeprubio I switched my CSS to `.header:hover img` but it seems to be worse as I don't see anything changing on hover. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Try with `.banner:hover` instead.

Comment: Your code as it stands seems to work: https://jsfiddle.net/t7h0t2ot/2/ . Have you checked the path to the image? Are you  sure you've got your selector correct? Please include the basic HTML structure to replicate the problem **in the question itself**. Trying to fix a "live" site you are working on is like trying to hit a moving target.

Comment: @zohirsalak-cena @jeprubio In fact I saw `<div class="logo navbar-left">` in my browser editor, I was thinking it was where I should link my css.

Comment: @jeprubio Also tried `.banner:hover` with not much luck either.

Comment: @Jon-P I added the HTML to the question, hope this can help to help :D

Comment: Grabbing what I assume is the appropriate part it still seems to work : https://jsfiddle.net/t7h0t2ot/3/ . What happens if you try applying the css without the hover. i.e. `.logo img`? Do you get the swapped image?

Comment: @Jon-P ah good idea! I tried that and it seems the problem is here. I only have a blank space now.

Comment: The problem is with my replacement image I think. But I've got no problem seeing the image alone in the browser. [link](https://jsfiddle.net/t7h0t2ot/4/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your image is bigger than what you specify. Not the comments in the CSS say "size of new image". Your image is much bigger than this and the top left 50 x 50 pixel area is white, so it looks like it is not working.

You need to use `background-size:contain;`

```css
.logo:hover img {
  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/logo-Couillart.gif) no-repeat;
  width: 50px;
  /* Width of new image */
  height: 50px;
  /* Height of new image */
  padding-left: 50px;
  /* Equal to width of new image */
  background-size: contain;
}

.logo img {
  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo navbar-left">
  <a href="http://couill.art" title="Couillard"><img src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/logo-Couillart-gif.png" alt="logo"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Was just going to say the same. With `background-size` you can shrink it to the size of the img element.

Answer (score 3):

Try modifiying the line:
`.logo:hover img {`
to `.banner:hover {`
I would also suggest using the background size property to modify the size of the background picture so the element retains its initial size. (Otherwise it would only work if you hovered over the top left region of the image.

```css
/* All in one selector */
.banner {
  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://www.picture-newsletter.com/arctic/arctic-06_small.jpg) no-repeat;
  width: 180px; /* Width of new image */
  height: 236px; /* Height of new image */
  padding-left: 180px; /* Equal to width of new image */
  background-size: 100% 100%; 
}

.banner:hover {
    display: block;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: url(http://www.picture-newsletter.com/arctic/arctic-02_small.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 50px, 50px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <title>Really Cool Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- .header would be across site on other pages with different children, so no background image adding -->
  <div class="header">
    <img class="banner" src="http://www.picture-newsletter.com/arctic/arctic-03_small.jpg">
  </div>
</body>
```

For the snippet you provided you need to include `background-size: 100%, 100%;`

```css
.logo img, .logo {
  width: 50px;
  /* Width of new image */
  height: 50px;
}


.logo:hover img {
  display: block;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: url(http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/logo-Couillart.gif) no-repeat;
  width: 50px;
  /* Width of new image */
  height: 50px;
  /* Height of new image */
  padding-left: 50px;
  /* Equal to width of new image */
  background-size: 100%, 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="logo navbar-left">
    <a href="http://couill.art" title="Couillard">
        <img src="http://couill.art/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/logo-Couillart-gif.png" alt="logo">
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: I've added your example - change `.logo img {` to `.logo img, .logo {` to prevent the change from happening by hovering anywhere on the line.